# How to create a read-only, thread-safe, global static in rust?

Tags: rust

Ideally I'd like to have a thread-safe read-only static/global that is evaluated at compile time.  I've read the docs on lazy_static, thread_local as well as const fn, but can't quite put them together cleanly.

Using H160 from the `primitive_types` crate, I'd love to have the following (not real code):
`static const ADDR: H160 = H160::from_str("0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7").unwrap();`

The address string is known at compile time, however `from_str()` isn't marked const, so is runtime only.  I don't need mutability, and the underlying data (`H160` wraps a `[u8; 20]`) should be safe to Copy.

The actual creation of the object is fast (~100ns), but not nearly as fast as a copy (~8ns) (unless my benchmarks are incorrect - very possibly).

I'm fine with explicitly calling an initialization function as the first thing in main() to setup the fields, and taking the responsibility of UB.  However the wrapping every access in unsafe{} is tedious...  I'd love for it to be a non-mut static that was evaluated at compile time.

Using lazy_static/thread_local looks like it has some overhead for checking if the item is initialized on each access, which I'd like to avoid.

A quick benchmark (please point out if it is incorrect!) shows a significant difference between the two...

```
use std::str::FromStr;

use criterion::{criterion_group, criterion_main, Criterion, black_box};
use primitive_types::H160;

static mut static_addr: H160 = H160::zero();

fn address_copy_static() -> H160 {
  unsafe {
    static_addr
  }
}

fn address_create() -> H160 {
  H160::from_str("0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7").unwrap()
}

fn criterion_benchmark(c: &mut Criterion) {
  unsafe {
    static_addr = H160::from_str("0xdAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7").unwrap();
  }
  c.bench_function("address_create", |b| b.iter(|| black_box(address_create())));
  c.bench_function("address_copy_static", |b| b.iter(|| black_box(address_copy_static())));
}

criterion_group!(benches, criterion_benchmark);
criterion_main!(benches);
```

```
Running benches/benchmark_address.rs (target/release/deps/benchmark_address-a8cf631aaf6d6831)
address_create          time:   [104.61 ns 106.29 ns 108.51 ns]
address_copy_static     time:   [8.6935 ns 8.8084 ns 8.9692 ns]
```

Comment: But you didn't benchmark the overhead of `lazy_static` (or `once_cell`), which is _very_ small (a practically 100% well predictable branch).

Comment: Also, are you sure you really need those nanoseconds?

Comment: In case `once_cell` is not an option (which I don't believe is the case), you can look for my crate [`init-token`](https://docs.rs/init-token). It provides a zero-cost access to the data, at the cost of having to carry a (ZST, so no runtime overhead) token around.

Comment: Unfortuantely I'm not sure exactly how best to bench once_cell.  My understanding is it acquires a mutex for read, which is zero-overhead on single-threaded benchmarks, so we'd be looking at multithreaded benchmarks, which are going to measure differently.  I'll see if I can write up a bench that tests it, but my assumption is any mutex is going to be slower than the non-lock version.

Unfortunately for performance, we're in the nanosecond range :(  This (larger section) is being rewritten from go, where it is <5us, so just reading a constant 20 bytes can't take 100ns, as it adds up quickly.

Comment: No, it doesn't acquire a mutex. It does something like that for the first initialization, but this is cold; after that, it does a simple read-only atomic check, essentially load, compare and jump. This should be ~free with correct branch prediction, which is guaranteed since the value will never be deinitialized.

Comment: Very interesting!  Thanks so much, I saw the mutex/deadlock mentions on the github and didn't look deeper at implementation.

Comment: You could use a macro like [hex_lit](https://docs.rs/hex_lit/) to convert the string into a `[u8; 20]` at compile time, and then construct the `H160` literally. `H160(hex!("dAC17F958D2ee523a2206206994597C13D831ec7"))`